# Google Chrome 404 custom error page

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, web, header, chromium

When a page doesn't exist in my website, Google Chrome shows "Oops! This link appears to be broken.". Firefox display my 404 error page. I want to do that with Chrome too.
Is it possible?

Comment: Chrome shows the 404... look @ http://stackoverflow.com/doesnotexist - the Oops page shows up for me when I type in a domain that does not resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the size of your 404 page is larger than 512 bytes? Based on a couple Google searches, it appears Chrome shares this feature with IE, where it will override 404 pages smaller than 512 bytes.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/webdesign/google-chrome.shtml, item 5 (as of seemingly September 2008).